# Get current user's location in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.2. I want to display the current user's location on a map. I am trying to use geocoder for the same. Unexpectedly, the `request.location` doesn't show the expected data.

```
>request.location
=> #<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007fed262bf690
@cache_hit=nil,
@data=
  {"ip"=>"::1",
   "city"=>"",
   "region_code"=>"",
   "region_name"=>"",
   "metrocode"=>"",
   "zipcode"=>"",
   "latitude"=>"0",
   "longitude"=>"0",
   "country_name"=>"Reserved",
   "country_code"=>"RD"}>

> request.remote_ip
=> "::1"
> request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
=> "::1"
```

Any suggestions? This needs to work in all environments.

Comment: it appears that you are accessing this via localhost, so it is giving you the correct location (IE localhost).  Geocoder uses the network address to get the user's approximate location, so this is working like expected..  You will need to use a different solution if you want to query the browser/device for the location information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder gets the address based on the ip address of the client. Since a client my be behind a VPN or another network, it's not reliable. I ended up using HTML5 geolocation which is reliable.